# Operators in C++ what does (::Type*)0 mean

Tags: c++

Can anyone tell me what this means?

```
(::Type*)0
```

actually it is part of this

```
return (is_modifytype()) ?
u.myfunction : (::Type*)0;
```

Comment: It means that this is old code that should be rewritten to use `nullptr`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It means "cast the integer `0` (using a C-style cast) to the type `Trip*` (`Trip` pointer) found in the global namespace (`::`)".

It should just use `nullptr` - as in

```
return is_modifyCurrentTrip() ?
    u.modifyCurrentTrip : nullptr;
```

Note: using `::` explicitly to designate the global namespace prevents the compiler from prepending any namespace names itself - this is completely irrelevant when just using `nullptr` though.